# IndexingError: Too many indexers

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I created a function to do many things, and one of them is storing the values of each rows of a data frame in the variable valueCol, however when I run it, it displays an error of too many indexes. To iterate along the columns I have used a for loop.
The dataframe where I want to extract the values is:

```
    val01_ambient_temperature   val01_ambient_winddir   val01_ambient_windspeed
measure_time            
2019-01-01 00:00:00 10.75   54.699997   9.20
2019-01-01 00:10:00 10.00   54.810001   9.50
2019-01-01 00:20:00 10.00   53.139999   8.50
2019-01-01 00:30:00 10.00   54.400002   8.87
2019-01-01 00:40:00 10.00   50.920002   9.25
```

I have tried the model with one column, removing the for loop and it works. The problem is when I introduce the counter in the iloc to identify the column that I am storing.

Function

```
def autoArimaModelVar(dataModel,dataTotal,dataTotalCopy,counter1):
...
    valueCol=pd.DataFrame(dataTotalCopy.iloc[:,counter1]) # -----XXXX--- problem here with counter
```

Call to the function

```
dataImport_selVar_copy=dataImport_selVar # not to modify original data
counterTest=0

for column in dataImport_selVar100:
    if counterTest==0: #initialize
        result01=autoArimaModelVar(dataImport_selVar100[column],dataImport_selVar[column],
                             dataImport_selVar_copy[column],counterTest)
    else:


result11=autoArimaModelVar(dataImport_selVar100[column],dataImport_selVar[column], dataImport_selVar_copy[column],counterTest)
result01=result01.append(result11,sort=False) #print only 18

    counterTest +=1
```

I expected to get the valueCol appended, dispaying something like this:

```
measure_time      value     signal          
2019-01-01 00:00:00 10.75   val01_ambient_temperature
2019-01-01 00:10:00 10.00   val01_ambient_temperature
2019-01-01 00:20:00 10.00   val01_ambient_temperature
2019-01-01 00:30:00 10.00   val01_ambient_temperature
2019-01-01 00:40:00 10.00   val01_ambient_temperature            
2019-01-01 00:00:00 54.699997  val01_ambient_winddir
2019-01-01 00:10:00 54.810001  val01_ambient_winddir
2019-01-01 00:20:00 53.139999  val01_ambient_winddir
2019-01-01 00:30:00 54.400002  val01_ambient_winddir
2019-01-01 00:40:00 50.920002  val01_ambient_winddir          
2019-01-01 00:00:00 9.20  val01_ambient_windspeed
2019-01-01 00:10:00 9.50  val01_ambient_windspeed
2019-01-01 00:20:00 8.50  val01_ambient_windspeed
2019-01-01 00:30:00 8.87  val01_ambient_windspeed
2019-01-01 00:40:00 9.25  val01_ambient_windspeed
```

However I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-294-8229f0a1b81e> in <module>
      9     if counterTest==0: #inicialize
     10         result01=autoArimaModelVar(dataImport_selVar100[column],dataImport_selVar[column],
---> 11                              dataImport_selVar_copy[column],counterTest)
     12     else:
     13         result11=autoArimaModelVar(dataImport_selVar100[column],dataImport_selVar[column],

<ipython-input-293-965350b41f10> in autoArimaModelVar(dataModel, dataTotal, dataTotalCopy, counter1)
     40 
     41     # Create a column called value with the value of the measures
---> 42     valueCol=pd.DataFrame(dataTotalCopy.iloc[:,counter1]) # -----XXXX--- problem here with counter
     43 
     44     # Concatenate using the index, the values and the forecast

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1470             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1471                 pass
-> 1472             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1473         else:
   1474             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2011     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
   2012 
-> 2013         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2014         try:
   2015             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    218         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    219             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
--> 220                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
    221             try:
    222                 self._validate_key(k, i)

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Comment: What is the expected output supposed to be?

Comment: The expected output is supposed to be:

Answer (score 0):

solved, since it is part of the for loop so it has been indexed, you should not index it again.

```
valueCol=dataTotalCopy
```